# SSRS Static Column Counter

Tags: reporting-services

I want to have a gauge for each row returned in my dataset. Is there a way to set the number of columns to be static and the number of rows be dynamic? So if I set the columns to 3 and the dataset returned 5 rows, that the output would be 2 rows (3 in the first, 2 in the second)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your query returns a unique row number for each record:

```
SELECT
   SalesOrderID,
   OrderDate,
   ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Then set your row group to group by the expression

```
=Fields!RowNumber.Value \ 3
```

Note the backslash to keep integer division.

and your column grouping to

```
=Fields!RowNumber.Value mod 3
```

Comment: It doesn't like the % for the column group function.

Comment: The GroupExpression for the tablix 'Tablix1' contains an error:[BC30037] Character is not valid.

Comment: We are getting closer. It's doing dynamic rows with 3 fixed columns, but it's staggering the data.

Comment: blank   data   blank<br />
blank   blank  data<br />
data    blank  blank<br />
blank   data   blank<br />

Comment: This got it to work http://nederveld.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/how-to-do-a-column-layout-in-sql-reporting-services/

Comment: You should either add an answer to this question with that approach and accept it as the answer, or I can modify my answer to point at the same and use the same functions.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this approach
http://nederveld.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/how-to-do-a-column-layout-in-sql-reporting-services/